# How do I use OpenDKIM with multiple domain names on a single server?

Tags: email-server, domain-name, dkim, txt-record

How do I use OpenDKIM with multiple domain names on a single server?

I own 3 domain names, and I have a single server that's running postfix for sending email. How do I use OpenDKIM?

Can I use the same keyfile for all 3 domain names? Do I have to create a TXT record for each domain name?

Comment: Haven't used OpenDKIM (but have used dkim-milter) - I find [DKIMProxy](http://dkimproxy.sourceforge.net) to be easier to setup than a milter. In general, you do need a TXT record for every domain that you wish a recipient to verify and you can use the same keyfile for all (although it is preferable for each domain to have its own keyfile). The configuration of OpenDKIM can be found on its [site](http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim-README).

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to set up a KeyTable with a separate line for each selector/domain/keyfile. It would look like this:

```
default._domainkey.example1.com example1.com:default:/etc/mail/dkim/keys/example1.com/default
default._domainkey.example2.com example2.com:default:/etc/mail/dkim/keys/example2.com/default
default._domainkey.example3.com example3.com:default:/etc/mail/dkim/keys/example3.com/default
```

then a SigningTable to determine who can sign on each domain:

```
*@example1.com default._domainkey.example1.com
*@example2.com default._domainkey.example2.com
*@example3.com default._domainkey.example3.com
```

Here's an easy How-To for setting it up:

http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2010/09/how-to-get-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-on-centos-5-5-and-postfix-using-opendkim/

Comment: Thanks SteveJ! Is it allowed to use the same default.private key for all 3 domains? Or does that invalidate or confuse the authentication process?

Comment: If you are using subdomains of the same domain, you can just specify `Subdomains yes` in `/etc/opendkim.conf`

Comment: As of January 2022, the linked How-To isn't reachable. Here's a link to a snapshot of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20210123113508/https://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2010/09/how-to-get-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-on-centos-5-5-and-postfix-using-opendkim/

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit dated, but the following configuration works for me.
The selector is usually `default`, but can be anything as long as you don't have multiple keys with the same selector.

```bash
SELECTOR=default
DOMAIN=domain.tld
# Add a rule for the new domain to the signing table (location of the signing table should be configured in opendkim.conf)
echo -e "*@${DOMAIN} ${SELECTOR}._domainkey.${DOMAIN}" | sudo tee -a /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
# Add the path to the key to the key table (again, defined in opendkim.conf)
echo -e "${SELECTOR}._domainkey.${DOMAIN} ${DOMAIN}:${SELECTOR}:/etc/opendkim/keys/${DOMAIN}/${SELECTOR}.private" | sudo tee -a /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
# Add the domain to the trusted hosts (I think this is not necessary if you send from localhost)
echo -e "${DOMAIN}" | sudo tee -a /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
# Create a directory for the domain's key
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opendkim/keys/${DOMAIN}
# Create the key
sudo opendkim-genkey -b 1024 -d ${DOMAIN} -D /etc/opendkim/keys/${DOMAIN} -s ${SELECTOR} -v
# Set the right ownership for the newly generated key
sudo chown opendkim: /etc/opendkim/keys -R
# This is the public key and must be added to your dns record
sudo cat /etc/opendkim/keys/${DOMAIN}/${SELECTOR}.txt
```

This was my source:
https://easydmarc.com/blog/how-to-configure-dkim-opendkim-with-postfix/