# Sign with one DKIM key for all subdomains

Tags: dkim

I've set up DKIM key for primary domain as per this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134725/setup-dkim-domainkeys-for-ubuntu-postfix-and-mailman

Can I use the same key to sign for subdomains as well?  If so, how?

Comment: Possibly yes. See answer in similar question http://serverfault.com/a/298718/218590

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow missed that answer in my searches.  Works perfectly.